# How do I read/connect BLE beacon on ESP32 with Arduino IDE?

Tags: iot, arduino-ide, esp32

I wish to connect my ESP32 to my JDY-08 paired with Arduino for some smart sensor application. I wanted to read the integer which I have sent with the JDY-08 set on iBeacon mode. I tried the example that came along with the library ESP32, the one named BLE_CLient in ESP32_BLE_Arduino. The code could find the device I'm using which is the JDY-08 combined with Arduino UNO. I check the service and char UUID with my nRF app. Can any one tell what is wrong?

JDY-08 Code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(2, 3);

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  mySerial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
  float temperature = 0.0;
  int sample;
  float ten_samples = 0.0;

  for (sample = 0; sample < 10; sample++) {
      temperature = ((float)analogRead(A0) * 5.0 / 1024.0) - 0.5;
      temperature = temperature / 0.01;
      delay(100);
      ten_samples = ten_samples + temperature;
  }

  temperature = ten_samples / 10.0;
  int temperature_translate = (int)temperature;
  mySerial.print(temperature_translate);
  Serial.print(temperature_translate);
  ten_samples = 0.0;

  if (mySerial.available())
    Serial.write(mySerial.read());
  if (Serial.available())
    mySerial.write(Serial.read());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use WEB Bluetooth API to do some checks, using it you can receive the data notifications you are sending from your ESP32.

So, first, take a look if you can receive the data coming from ESP32 using this web interface: 
https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-bluetooth/notifications.html

Make sure UUID's are properly set, I've found that for the JDY-08 like devices short UUID identifications as 0x35655 may not be enough, you need to get the long versions of them, they look more like 0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, this may be happening with your ESP32 UUID's as well, so check'em with this tools:

https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-bluetooth/

In resume:

- Use WEB Bluetooth API to get info and connect to the devices
- Double check UUID's of services and characteristics

If this works but you still can not receive with the JDY-08:

- Check TX and RX positions, they may be inverted

**The problem is not on the posted code.**